# Como poder utilizar counter(properti) en una funcion calc CSS

Tags: css, css3, sass, stylus

Tengo algunos items que deseo dimencionar con cunter.

```css
body {
  
  counter-reset: properti;
}

li::after {
  counter-increment: properti;
  content: counter(properti) ;
}

li{
  background: red;
  width: calc(25% * counter(properti));
}
```

```html
<ul>
  
  <li> texto: </li>
  <li> texto: </li>
  <li> texto: </li>
  <li> texto: </li>


</ul>
```

Se que se puede hacer esto porque cal hace cálculos con enteros

Comment: En una expresión `calc` sólo puede haber _literales_ y otras expresiones _calc_. No se puede usar `counter()` que, de hecho, devuelve texto, no un número. Has puesto en las etiquetas [tag:sass] , ¿te valdría una solución hecha en SCSS?

Comment: Si estoy codificando todo en SASS, En w3schools vi los valores que soportaban y que retornaban respectivamente. Si hay otra solución en sass estaría perfecto. Hasta el momento solo lo he podido resolver con javascript

Comment: ¿Y la etiqueta `stylus`?

Answer (score 1):

Como he puesto en un comentario, dentro de la expresión de `calc` sólo puede haber literales y otras expresiones `calc`. No se puede usar `counter()` que, de hecho, devuelve texto, no un número. Y esto no parece que vaya a cambiar ya que los contadores suponen bastante sobrecarga para el navegador y no se recomienda su uso.

Una solución mejor es que el compilador de **sass** sea quien haga los cálculos.

```
li {
  background: red;

  @for $i from 1 through 4 {
    &:nth-child(4n + #{$i}) {
      width: (25% * $i);
      &::after {
        content: "#{$i}"; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Compilado queda:

```css
li {
  background: red;
}
li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  width: 25%;
}
li:nth-child(4n+1)::after {
  content: "1";
}
li:nth-child(4n+2) {
  width: 50%;
}
li:nth-child(4n+2)::after {
  content: "2";
}
li:nth-child(4n+3) {
  width: 75%;
}
li:nth-child(4n+3)::after {
  content: "3";
}
li:nth-child(4n+4) {
  width: 100%;
}
li:nth-child(4n+4)::after {
  content: "4";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> texto: </li>
  <li> texto: </li>
  <li> texto: </li>
  <li> texto: </li>
</ul>
```

Si se quiere, se puede generalizar para cualquier número de *escalones* que nos haga falta:

```
@mixin escalera($n: 4) {
  @for $i from 1 through $n {
    &:nth-child(#{$n}n + #{$i}) {
      width: (100% / $n * $i);
      &::after {
        content: "#{$i}"; 
      }
    }
  }
}

li {
  background: red;
  @include escalera(4);
}
```

Comment: El problema de hacerlo así es que no puedo hacerlo dinamicamente. Es decir en este caso son 4 items, pero podrían ser menos o mas. Esto ya lo resolví con javascript pero quería que esto quedara en la hoja de estilos.

Comment: este numero lo obtengo de una base de datos, después de que se compilo sass.